# Discord.js Level System

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

My 'problem' is more of a feature I am looking to add, I used this guide:
https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system
I changed the code a little to mainly give you a random amount of XP, I am looking to edit how much XP is needed to level up.

Right now it is a static amount, being 5000 needed to level up. I am trying to make it increase the amount needed to level up by an extra 5000 each time you level up.

Currently, it works like this:

> Level 1 to 2 = 5000 total XP needed
>
> Level 2 to 3 = 10000 total xp needed

Currently, the amount needed to level up is always 5000 between each level.

This is how I want it to work:

> Level 1 to 2 = 5000 total XP needed
>
> Level 2 to 3 = 15000 total XP needed

Which will be 5000 to level 2 and then 10000 to level 3 and so on (increasing the amount needed by 5000 each time you level up)

I spent the best part of 2 hours trying different things, and mainly looking at the code being completely out of my depth.
I believed that doing something like this would work, but I have no idea if it's correct

```js
if (score.level == '1') {
    nextLevel = 5000
}
if (score.level == '2' {
    nextLevel = 10000
}
```

I highly doubt this is correct, otherwise, my message event would be very long, as I plan to have 100 levels

The code in its entirety:

```js
    let score;
    if (message.guild) {
        score = bot.getScore.get(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        if (!score) {
            score = {
                id: `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`,
                user: message.author.id,
                guild: message.guild.id,
                points: 0,
                level: 1,
            };
        }
        const xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 50;
        const curxp = score.points;
        const curlvl = score.level;
        const nxtLvl = score.level * 5000;
        score.points = curxp + xpAdd;
        if (nxtLvl <= score.points) {
            score.level = curlvl + 1;
            const lvlup = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(
                    `Congrats ${message.author.username}`,
                    message.author.displayAvatarURL()
                )
                .setTitle('You have leveled up!')
                .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/lXeBiMs.png')
                .setColor(color)
                .addField('New Level', curlvl + 1);
            message.channel.send(lvlup).then(msg => {
                msg.delete({
                    timeout: 10000,
                });
            });
        }
        bot.setScore.run(score);
    }
```

The code as-is works fine and as expected, but as-is is not very good, as there is no reward from going from level 30-31 as it's the same amount of XP needed to get from level 1-2

Comment: This will work but this is a very **Hard Coded** way of doing this thing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a little formula which should do the trick (if I understand your problem correctly):

```js
const nxtLvl = 5000 * (Math.pow(2, score.level) - 1);
```

This gives the following xp requirements to level up:

```
1->2:  5000
2->3:  15000
3->4:  35000
4->5:  75000
5->6: 155000
```

Comment: @Dan how so? If you want to go from 2 to 3 the formula becomes `5000 * (Math.pow(2, 2) -1)` which is 15000 and if you want to go from 3 to 4 it becomes `5000 * (Math.pow(2, 3) -1)` which is 35000. It works fine for me

Comment: Fron what I understood, when ``` score.level = 3 ``` you want ``` nxtLvl = 30000 ``` because each time you want an increament of 5000 so:     ``` socre.level = 1; nxtLvl = 5000;.                            
     score.level = 2; nxtLvl = 15000;.                        
     score.level = 3; nxtLvl = 30000; And so on....     ```

Comment: This worked a dream! Although I then realized how high the XP needed was, so I altered it slightly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const levels = [0, 5000, 15000, 30000, 50000, 75000];
....
nextLevel = levels[score.level];
```

### Edit

@Dan you mean like this:

```
nextLevel = 5000 * Math.round( score.level * (score.level + 1) / 2 );
```

Comment: This will work but still quite hardcoded, you need to find a mathematical expression for levels. It seems like a mathematical sequence, more specifically, a **geometric progression**

Comment: I mean more like this: ```const nxtLvl = 10000 * (Math.pow(score.level - 1, 2) + 5000;``` But both of the expressions are quite good

Answer (score 0):

Here Is Code I'm Using
But Problem Is I Can't Add Or Remove XP
Also I Made It With Scratch So I'm Being Mad Understanding This

```
let Discord;
let Database;
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    Discord = DiscordJS;
    Database = EasyDatabase;
} else {
    Discord = require("discord.js");
    Database = require("easy-json-database");
}
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
const s4d = {
    Discord,
    client: null,
    tokenInvalid: false,
    reply: null,
    joiningMember: null,
    database: new Database("./db.json"),
    checkMessageExists() {
        if (!s4d.client) throw new Error('You cannot perform message operations without a Discord.js client')
        if (!s4d.client.readyTimestamp) throw new Error('You cannot perform message operations while the bot is not connected to the Discord API')
    }
};
s4d.client = new s4d.Discord.Client({
    fetchAllMembers: true
});
s4d.client.on('raw', async (packet) => {
    if (['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(packet.t)) {
        const guild = s4d.client.guilds.cache.get(packet.d.guild_id);
        if (!guild) return;
        const member = guild.members.cache.get(packet.d.user_id) || guild.members.fetch(d.user_id).catch(() => {});
        if (!member) return;
        const channel = s4d.client.channels.cache.get(packet.d.channel_id);
        if (!channel) return;
        const message = channel.messages.cache.get(packet.d.message_id) || await channel.messages.fetch(packet.d.message_id).catch(() => {});
        if (!message) return;
        s4d.client.emit(packet.t, guild, channel, message, member, packet.d.emoji.name);
    }
});
var member_xp, member_level;


s4d.client.login('My Dumb Token').catch((e) => {
    s4d.tokenInvalid = true;
    s4d.tokenError = e;
});

s4d.client.on('message', async (s4dmessage) => {
    if (!((s4dmessage.member).user.bot)) {
        member_xp = s4d.database.get(String(('xp-' + String(s4dmessage.author.id))));
        member_level = s4d.database.get(String(('level-' + String(s4dmessage.author.id))));
        if (!member_xp) {
            member_xp = 0;
        } else if (!member_level) {
            member_level = 0;
        }
        s4d.database.set(String(('xp-' + String(s4dmessage.author.id))), (member_xp + 1));
        member_xp = member_xp + 1;
        if (member_xp > 100) {
            s4d.database.set(String(('level-' + String(s4dmessage.author.id))), (member_level + 1));
            member_level = member_level + 1;
            s4dmessage.channel.send(String((['Congratulations, ', s4dmessage.member, 'you jumped to level ', member_level, '!!'].join(''))));
        }
        if ((s4dmessage.content) == '-level') {
            s4dmessage.channel.send(String(([s4dmessage.member, ', you are currently level: ', member_level].join(''))));
        } else if ((s4dmessage.content) == '-xp') {
            s4dmessage.channel.send(String(([s4dmessage.member, ', you need ', 100 - member_xp, ' to jump to level ', member_level + 1].join(''))));
        }
    }

});

s4d;
```